# 【Android Studio】When building project, it showed Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, aapt

When I first open Android Studio, it works well. However, when i try to build apk(test my code in the monitor), it broke up. I hava already turn off the offline mode, but it still doesnt't work and shows that cannot get the resources. If you have the same experience, please help me.

This is the build.gradle of the project
[image]

Here are wrong messesge in detail
[image]

Comment: Did you sync your project gradle in offline mode?

Comment: Can you try, Build -> Clean Project